# How to keep session alive for multiple test cases in Robot Framework?

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ui-automation

I need to keep my session alive in order to test multiple test cases in the Robot Framework using the selenium library.
For instance, if I go to a web-site and login on it, when I close my app and open it again, I need to log in again. I want to keep the session alive, just like it would be if I use Google Chrome.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [suite setup and teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) features of the framework for such cases.

You can define a keyword to be executed once before the test cases in a suite, this is called **Suite Setup**.

Also, you can define a keyword to be executed once after all test cases in a suite, this is called **Suite Teardown**.

Here is an example, where the browser (Firefox for me, but it does not matter) opened only once, and then four test cases use this browser. Here, all of them check if the current page is the same as the one used in the suite setup.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Suite Setup       Open Browser And Login       # Define keyword as suite setup here
Suite Teardown    Logout And Close Browser     # Define keyword as suite teardown here

*** Test Cases ***
Test A
    Location Should Be    https://stackoverflow.com/

Test B
    Location Should Be    https://stackoverflow.com/

Test C
    Location Should Be    https://stackoverflow.com/

Test D
    Location Should Be    https://stackoverflow.com/

    
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser And Login
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/    Firefox
    Log    Fake login
    
    
Logout And Close Browser
    Log    Fake logout
    Close All Browsers
```